# Dynamically modifying a form widget in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

My Django app uses Django Suit as a tool to theme the admin app of Django. One of the things Suit can do is append and prepend elements to form widgets like:

```
class PropertyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        widgets = {
            'amount': EnclosedInput(prepend = "GBP"),
        }
```

The  effect is:

[image]

Although this is a nice feature it would be more useful if I could add it dynamically like (in pseudo code):

```
'amount': EnclosedInput(prepend = my_model_instance.currency)
```

I tried to override the form's init like so:

```
class PropertyForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = kwargs["instance"]
        self._meta.widgets["amount"] = EnclosedInput(prepend = inst.currency)
        super(PropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Strangely that only works when I put a breakpoint in the **init** method. It looks like there's some timing issue involved.

So my question is what would be the best way (if one at all available) to implement this?

Comment: What you need is a widget that takes its value from more than one instance field. One way to do this is with `MultiValueField` and `MultiWidget`. If this is too hard to get working I could elaborate an answer.

Comment: I'm not too sure that's the way to go. When I look at the code for EnclosedInput (part of Django Suit), the widget is just an extension of the standard Django TextInput and the only thing they do is add a <span> with a CSS class to the HTML output of the widget. I'm actually baffled by the fact that my approach doesn't work without a breakpoint and a debugger halt...

Comment: What I meant is that you basically want a widget that includes the values from two different form fields. I see that as a more reusable solution than hacking the form constructor. As for debugger, maybe it forces the evaluation of some lazy object?

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I'll debug some more and see if I can unravel that mystery...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
self._meta.widgets["amount"] = EnclosedInput(prepend = inst.currency)
```

It turns out `_meta` is being cached. When I change the above line to (which also a nicer solution as _meta is probably private):

```
self.fields['amount'].widget = EnclosedInput(prepend = inst.currency)
```

...it works flawlessly

Comment: Note that you need to call `super()` before trying to access the fields.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to configure a form class each time you need it:

```
def make_property_form(currency):
    class PropertyForm(forms.Form):
        # ...
        widgets = {
            'amount': EnclosedInput(prepend=currency),
        }
    return PropertyForm

def view_that_uses_my_form(request):
    # ...
    form_class = make_property_form(model.currency)
    form = form_class(the_usual_form_initialization)
```

Comment: The form is configured in the admin with form=PropertyForm, so that would mean I would need to add these methods to the PropertyAdmin class? I would also need to override the admin method that actually creates the form (probably the view_that_uses_my_form() method in your answer...

Comment: No, that would make my approach pretty useless in your case. It would only work if you explicitly built a new form instance at every use (like if you only used the form in your own view functions), but I wouldn't mess with the admin code for this.